# Mapping a grouped collection using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, collections, ienumerable, automapper, igrouping

I have the following code which is not working:

```
var groupedZones = this._zoneDataManager.GetZonesGroupedByCountry();
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, ZoneDTO>> zonesToReturn = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Zone>>, IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, ZoneDTO>>>(groupedZones);
```

I keep getting the following exception:

> The value
>   \"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SCGRE.Business.Model.ZoneDTO]\" is
>   not of type
>   \"System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,SCGRE.Business.Model.ZoneDTO]\"
>   and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name:
>   value

I do not understand why it is trying to map a `List<T>` into an `IGrouping<String, T>` or maybe I did not understand the exception properly... But I basically have an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Zone>>` and I want to map it to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, ZoneDTO>>`

Note that I have created a map from `Zone` to `ZoneDTO` as follows:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Zone, ZoneDTO>();
```

And that's because both classes have almost exactly the same properties.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've simplified it down and have run some unit tests, and unfortunately it doesn't look like IGrouping is currently supported. If you get no resolution from here, you could also try the [AutoMapper Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/automapper-users)

Answer (score 7):

After some work arround, I guess you cannot do some thing like

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, Zone>>, IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, ZoneDTO>>>()
```

To be specific, AutoMapper supports the source collection types include: (Only `Generic` types)

```
IEnumerable, IEnumerable<T>, ICollection, ICollection<T>, IList, IList<T>, List<T>, Arrays
```

AutoMapper will not support `IGrouping` because it is non-generic enumerable type.

Instead you can do the following simple approach,

```
var zones = this._zoneDataManager.GetZones();   // Write new method in your ZoneDataManager
var zoneDTOs = Mapper.Map<List<Zone>, List<ZoneDTO>>(zones);
IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, ZoneDTO>> zonesToReturn = zoneDTOs.GroupBy(z => z.Country);
```

Please read [this](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Lists%20and%20Arrays). Hope this helps.

Comment: @TaniaMaria, Did you tried with this approach? Please let me know.

Comment: I believe IGrouping is now supported. I'm able to successfully map from IGrouping<string, entity> to entityDto; and automapper automatically supports List<> to List<> mappings if the individual mappings are configured