# How do I Mapper.Map for IGrouping

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grouping, automapper

I'm having a problem when use AutoMapper

my code:

```
public static IQueryable<IGrouping<Int64, GroupTimeSheetViewModel>> ToListGroupViewModel(this IQueryable<IGrouping<Int64, GroupTimeSheet>> entity)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<IQueryable<IGrouping<Int64, GroupTimeSheet>>, IQueryable<IGrouping<Int64, GroupTimeSheetViewModel>>>(entity);
    }
```

when I run my code, I get error:

> The value "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PG.Admin.Models.TimeSheetHeaders.GroupTimeSheetViewModel]" is not of type "System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int64,PG.Admin.Models.TimeSheetHeaders.GroupTimeSheetViewModel]" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
>   Parameter name: value

Comment: check this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305391/mapping-a-grouped-collection-using-automapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper can't map queryables directly. If I were you, I'd use [AutoMapper's LINQ projection capabilities](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions). It uses LINQ to build out the Select projection. That way, your resultant LINQ would be something like:

```
dbContext.GroupTimeSheets
   .GroupBy(ts => ts.Something)
   .Project().To<GroupTimeSheetViewModel>()
   .ToListAsync();
```